# Is there a way to create a collision between the hair and body in my character in Blender 2.8?

Tags: particles

I tried creating a force field and also emitting the hair from a separate object but it keeps falling through the mesh. I'm new to Blender and might be missing a simple solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to solve this would be setting the particle emitter to *collision*. You can do this in the physics tab. There is an option labeled *collision*.

Comment: I tried this as well... is there any other possible solution?